# Why doesn't $_POST recognise certain files uploaded?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

You would not believe this fault, I have no idea what's going on. When I try to upload files, some of them refuse to upload.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
if ($_POST['fileadd']){
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    print_r($_POST); echo "<br>"; print_r($_FILES);
}
?>

        <form action="" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="bigtext" style="width: 80%;"> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="bigbutton" id="showloader" name="fileadd" value="Upload the song" />
        </form>


</body>
</html>
```

[Here it is in action.](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/589/rux.gif)
The problem is when it says *array 0* which it shouldn't say.

Also, how come when I choose certain files, the `$_POST` array is `nil/zero`, when it should at least have `fileadd` in it, as the name of the submit button?

Comment: You have no `move_uploaded_file()` function, in your posted code anyway. Show us your full code if that's not your full code. Look at the function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Have you checked the file size of the files that don't upload? They may be exceeding the limit configured in your server.

Comment: I have `move_uploaded_file()` on my website, but not all files submitted appear in `$_FILES` and `$_POST` appears empty even though I've posted.

Comment: I have a 15MB file size limit @BrendanBullen which I have not exceeded.

Comment: Nice song collection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Using `if ($_FILES['fileadd'] ){` makes it worse. Understand that on my real website, there are multiple forms, so the` submit button is named `fileadd`. Then once the submit button is clicked, looks for `$_POST['fileadd']`

Comment: @desbest Yes I know, that's why I deleted my comment after seeing what you wrote under Marc B's answer about the Submit button. You can also use `if(isset($_POST['fileadd']))`

Comment: @desbest You better post your full code then. I'm sure something else is causing this. Theoretically, `if(isset($_POST['fileadd']))` should be working. What you posted is not enough to be 100% sure.

Comment: Amazingly, `if(!isset($_POST['fileadd']))` makes it worse. It makes none of them upload instead of one. http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/5931/8uhc.gif

Comment: As simple as it seems, this is my whole code. Here it is as a Github Gist. https://gist.github.com/desbest/7387b29c950db89531dc

Comment: @desbest It's not `if(!isset($_POST['fileadd']))` but minus the `!` as in `if(isset($_POST['fileadd']))`

Comment: @desbest Now that is not full code. How do you expect it to upload without the `move_uploaded_file()` function? What are you trying to do anyway? It's got nowhere to go.

Comment: Here's my full code with the `move_uploaded_file()`. https://gist.github.com/desbest/a6050f34a7c57e7be8c7#file-upload-php-L56 taken from my website.

Comment: @desbest This may cause havoc, no quotes inside bracketed variable `if (empty($_POST[artist]))` and `elseif (empty($_POST[title]))` - try `if (empty($_POST['artist']))` and `elseif (empty($_POST['title']))` - also `$newSongCount = $artist[songcount] +1;` try `$newSongCount = $artist['songcount'] +1;`

Comment: @desbest Yet this `if ($_POST['fileadd']){` definitely needs to be `if(isset($_POST['fileadd']))`

Comment: I just tried it on my localhost and received this error when uploading a problematic file. `Warning: POST Content-Length of 12505771 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0` Could that be it/

Comment: @desbest That could very well be it. Check what your `max_upload_size` is set in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: I have this as my `php.ini` in my working directory where my php files are https://gist.github.com/desbest/7274d6ef5b1429cf10cb but when I checked by doing `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), ", " , ini_get('post_max_size');` in php, it echoed `8MB` twice. How can I fix that? I think my webhost is blocking me from changing the values of `php.ini`.

Comment: @desbest That is bizarre about the `8MB`. Try this in your `.htaccess` file unless there's something already in there `php_value upload_max_filesize 48M php_value post_max_size 48M` This will work only if the AllowOverride settings permit it.

Comment: @desbest You could also try this in your PHP code `ini_set('upload_max_filesize','48M'); 
ini_set('post_max_size','48M');` but `.htaccess` might be your best bet.

Comment: The `.htaccess` trick works. Thanks a lot! (`ini_set` does not work on my localhost, but does on my server. It's vice versa.)

Comment: @desbest Great, glad to hear it. You're welcome.

Comment: @desbest I should probably put it in as answer in order to close this question, because it will remain in the unanswered category, since a solution was in fact found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing full code and conversing with the OP on finding a solution to the problem at hand, have concluded the problem to be the following points:

This:

```
if ($_POST['fileadd']){
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
if(isset($_POST['fileadd']))
```

in order to check if the Submit button has been set.

Also the upload max size was set too low in accordance with the size of files attempted to be uploaded, using the following in `.htaccess` to increase it.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 48M
php_value post_max_size 48M
```

Comment: And in case the `.htaccess` trick doesn't work, you can use `ini_set('upload_max_filesize','15M'); ini_set('post_max_size','15M');` inside your php file, and then use `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), ", " , ini_get('post_max_size');` to check the values. Alternatively you can use [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/desbest/7274d6ef5b1429cf10cb) in your `php.ini` file in your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You're simply assuming that your code is perfect. It's not. It assumes that file uploads ALWAYS succeed, and doesn't allow for the possibility of failure. You need to have something more like:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("File upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Yes, but considelring that the submit button named `fileadd` exists, why when I upload certain files, does `$_POST` become blank?

Comment: You shouldn't be checking for form fields to determine if a POST occurred. Use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ... }`. It's 100% reliable.

Comment: I've tried that, and `$_POST` still comes up empty when I upload particular files.

Comment: @desbest Try using `if(isset($_POST['fileadd']))` see if that makes a difference then.